# Do Rails 3 routes still have the singular option?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

You used to be able to do:

```
resources :posts, :singular => true
```

But I tried this in Rails and it didn't work. Does anyone know the new way or workaround?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use resource :post

You can check out the [edgeguides section](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources) for guides on edge-rails, I don't know for certain how up to date they are but I found them to be quite correct.

Comment: Yea that guide helped. You can still do :singular => true